# Can we consider high correlation to be a good predictor?

Tags: prediction, correlation

The problem of predicting the daily number of COVID-19 cases is indeed challenging and many (external) factors should be taken into account to come up with a reasonable predictor. However, we have studied Twitter for a specific country (not English) for the period Mar-Nov 2020, and found out that the volume of daily tweets related to symptom X is highly correlated with the number of confirmed cases in that country (pearson correlation `0.84` with p-value `0.00031`).

In the field of data science, would this suffice, at least partially, to say daily tweets of X is a good predictor for the number of COVID-19 cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this a variant of the ["Google Flu Trends"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Flu_Trends) story from a few years back? (Substitute "Google" with "Twitter" and "Flu" with "Covid-19", "Searches" with "Tweets".

Long story. In a nutshell, frequency of Google Searches for terms like "Flu", "Headache" "Nausea" were an excellent predictor for flu season forecasting, until they weren't. (when people started to search for "flu trends"? I don't remember why).  There was a negative feedback loop, and forecasts became less reliable.)

Google finally removed that feature, to avoid criticism and to stay out of trouble.

There are [many papers](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22google+flu+trends%22&btnG=) on this, and why it was taken offline.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. They should have updated the model periodically. Will check the papers.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would fit a linear model (`lm(tweets ~ cases)`) and then use bootstrap or cross-validation to test the model.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think linear model will fit as the curve is going down. It is more like a bell curve.

Comment: Then the correlation coefficient does not indicate tweets are a good predictor. Correlation coefficient assumes linearity.

Comment: You will also find correlation coefficient and the linear regression coefficient are related. See what happens when you center tweets and cases before fitting the linear regression model.